# PHP not receiving formData object from ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm testing out sending a formData object to PHP (I am following http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/uploading-files-with-ajax/), but am having some difficulty getting it off the ground. First, the formData object is created and populated with:

```
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append('my_key','my_value');
```

Then my ajax call with jQuery is:

```
  $.ajax({
     url: 'php_upload.php',
     type: 'POST',
     cache: false,
     data: formdata,
     processData: false,
     contentType: false,
     success: function (response) {
     console.log(response);
  }
  });
```

With the php_upload.php file containing:

```
<?php
    echo $_FILES['my_key']['name'];
?>
```

But I get an undefined index: my_key error in the console.

Anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong? Been scratching my head for ages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You haven't added any files to the FormData, just a string which can be accessed by `$_POST['my_key']`.

To pass a file the second parameter of FormData.append has to be a [`FILE`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/File) or a [`BLOB`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/blob).

Comment: Ahh I see. Got it working now - thanks! (It turned out that it was the FileReader I wasn't understanding correctly instead)